# PyQt4 style QTableView/QTableWidget cell to look like horizontalHeader

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I'm having to create a custom table manually with Qt4 (I need 2 header rows/columns).
To do that, I've disabled horizontalHeader/verticalHeader's, and have created the header rows.
Now, I'd like to style those table cells like the header cells are styled, but I don't see how to do that.

Anybody able to help?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Why do you have two headers? Can a column/row have to different titles> I really cannot think of a use for that. Can you elaborate your question more?

Comment: I'm designing a table that requires 2 header rows and 2 header columns.  The top column is the Title of the column, the 2nd header is the weight.  Something like this:  http://imagebin.ca/view/VYoqL6T9.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have more than one line in a table header in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336079/can-i-have-more-than-one-line-in-a-table-header-in-qt)