# Can I have more than one line in a table header in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm using Qt4 and I have a `QTableView` which displays data using a custom model.  I'd like to have two rows in the table header,  ideally with some of the cells in the first row spanning multiple columns.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too was looking for a solution to this problem.  I've found this class:
[HierarchicalHeaderView](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/HierarchicalHeaderView?content=103154)
at qt-apps.org by user Barmaglodd (Krasnoshchekov Petr).

That solution goes over and beyond what you (and I) need.  Also, I cannot use their solution due to their copyright notice.

[This post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/09/28/qt-support-weekly-27-widgets-on-a-header/) from blog.qt.digia.com by Andy Shaw shows you how to overlay QComboBoxes over a header.  In my solution, I've done the same thing with another header view.  This is similar to how they [overlaid a QTableView on a QTableView for the Qt Frozen column example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-frozencolumn-example.html).  For this solution, you do need to subclass both the QTableWidget and QHeaderView.  Also, if you want to let the user adjust column width that takes extra work.

Tip: overload the SizeHint to give a height 2x of the normal height of the 'main' headerview, align the text of the main header view to the bottom and draw the other headerview on top of the normal one, do this in the

```
showEvent(QShowEvent* e)
```

method.

Comment: Your first link is great, but I wonder in which circumstances you may find BSD licensed code unusable due to license?

Comment: @Predelnik, I'm not sure; I must have confused the license of this project with another.

Answer (score 7):

I've had a similar problem regarding the multiple headder lines of a QTableView. I solved it using a simple "\n" in the column header text.

Answer (score 3):

Under the impression of [HierarchicalHeaderView](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/HierarchicalHeaderView?content=103154) I've made a Python port of it and a simple model to display pandas DataFrames with multilevel headers (MultiIndex) in QTableView.

Here're the first results [dataframemodel](https://github.com/Winand/dataframemodel). upd: it's quite slow with big DataFrames

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom header by making a `QTableWidgetItem` and then using the `setHorizontalHeaderItem()`. The method takes a column number, so I am not sure if that will allow for spanning multiple columns natively -- however, at the very least you could use the same `QTableWidgetItem` for several columns.

As far as using two rows in the header, I do not believe this is currently supported.  However, you could probably add this functionality by rolling your own derived class of `QTableWidget` if you are ambitious.

Answer (score 0):

I will write my solution, perhaps it is a crutch. But I redefined `QHeaderView` and in it, instead of the standard cells, I used my own double ones. These double cells are essentially a `QTableWidget` without a header.

```
class CHeaderView : public QHeaderView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CHeaderView(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *e) override;
    void SetHeight(const size_t& Height);
    void AddCell(const CHeaderCellData&);
    void AddCell(const QString& header, const QStringList& subHeaders = QStringList());
private slots:
    void ResizeHeader();
private:
    std::vector<CHeaderViewCell*> m_HeaderCells;
};
```

```
CHeaderViewCell::CHeaderViewCell(const int rowNumber, const int columnsNumber, QWidget* parent)
    : m_CellData(new QTableWidget(rowNumber, columnsNumber, parent))
    , m_Rows(rowNumber)
    , m_Columns(columnsNumber)
{
    m_CellData->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    m_CellData->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

    m_CellData->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
    m_CellData->setEnabled(false);

    /* Hide Headers */
    m_CellData->verticalHeader()->hide();
    m_CellData->horizontalHeader()->hide();

    m_CellData->horizontalHeader()->setMinimumSectionSize(25);

}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

The links regarding HierarchicalHeaderView are dead, here is a working link:
https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1132194
(sorry I can't comment yet)